# PHP echo statement IF parse error

Tags: php

```
if ((isset($_GET['Menu']) && $_GET['Menu'] == "1" && $_GET['Overview']==1)
{
 echo '$_GET['Overview']'
}
```

if statement to receive parameter from the URL

Comment: Even if this syntax was correct, `class="select"` would appear before the tag.

Comment: You have to connect the echo items put a .(dot) before if and also after }. and change 'class="select"' to 'class=select'.

Comment: with the dot I still get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: Did you change the class too?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to `echo` every part of your code:

```
echo "<li><a ";
 if($_GET['Menu']==1) { echo 'class="select"'; } 
echo " href=javascript:setParam('Menu',1);>Networks</a></li>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Because you cannot use `if` the way you do. Split up the `echo`, then it should work:

```
echo "<li><a " ;
if($_GET['Menu']==1) { echo 'class="select"'; } 
echo " href=javascript:setParam('Menu',1);>Networks</a></li>";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$x="";
if($_GET['Menu']==1)
$x= 'class="select"';

echo "<li><a>".$x." href=javascript:setParam('Menu',1);>Networks</a></li>";
```

Comment: Please, consider adding any explanation or comment. Code-only answers are often flagged as Very Low Quality and are eventually closed.

Answer (score -2):

Im partial to `sprintf` for concatenation, but thats just me:

```
echo sprintf('<li><a %s href=javascript:setParam(\'Menu\',1);>Networks</a></li>', 
    $_GET['Menu']==1 ? 'class="select"' : '');
```